# Componente criado não fica com a largura da tela

Tags: android

Criei um componente que seria uma barra com botões na parte inferior da tela. Ela deve respeitar tanto em portrait como em landscape a largura da tela no mínimo. Caso a largura do componente passe o da tela estou usando um HorizontalScrollView. O componente não esta ficando com a largura no mínimo da tela:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        style="@style/ButtonApp_Theme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:background="@color/Transparente"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/1"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        style="@style/ButtonApp_Theme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:background="@color/Transparente"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/2"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/2"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        style="@style/ButtonApp_Theme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:background="@color/Transparente"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/3"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/3"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        style="@style/ButtonApp_Theme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:background="@color/Transparente"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/4"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/4"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

No layout onde insiro o componente criado estou usando android:layout_width="fill_parent" e mesmo assim não esta sendo respeitado a largura independente da largura (a largura da tela sendo maior que do componente).

```
public class BottomBarButton extends HorizontalScrollView implements
    OnClickListener {

private Button btn1;
private Button btn2;
private Button btn3;
private Button btn4;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

public BottomBarButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    intitializer(context);
}

public BottomBarButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    intitializer(context);
}

private void intitializer(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bottom_bar_button, this);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnV1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.btn1:
        Toast.makeText(context, "btn1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        break;

    case R.id.btn2:
        Toast.makeText(context, "btn2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        break;

    case R.id.btn3:
        Toast.makeText(context, "btn3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        break;

    case R.id.btn4:
        Toast.makeText(context, "btn4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Está utilizando `fillViewPort="true"` no `HorizontalScrollView`?

Comment: @Wakim, era isto mesmo! Havia somente informado o fillViewPort no layout do componente e não no layout da view. Obrigado!

Comment: Irei colocar como resposta, para que possa aceitar a solução, ok?

Comment: Ok tudo bem! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para forçar que o `HorizontalScrollView` ocupe todo o espaço disponível no pai use o atributo `fillViewport="true"` na declaração do componente no XML.